# Field or property field does not exist error

Tags: sharepoint-server, vuejs

I get the following error when I run the code below.
**'Field or property "Title" does not exist. undefined'**

Anyone know why that is?  The ***Title*** field does exist.

I'm also using Vue.js

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.6/vue.min.js"></script>  
</head>

<body>

<div id="app">
{{ test }}
  <table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Department of Veterans Affairs</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Memorandum</td>      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Date:</td>     
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">From:</td>     
      <td></td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Subj:</td>     
      <td></td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">To:</td>     
      <td></td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">In accordance with....</td>  
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <table border="1" width="100%">
          <tr>
                <td colspan="2">1.</td>     
                <td>This memorandum has been prepared .....to support:</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                  <textarea rows="4" cols="150" v-model="guidance1">

                  </textarea>
                </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
                <td colspan="2">2.</td>     
                <td>This memorandum has been prepared .....to support:</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                  <textarea rows="4" cols="150" v-model="guidance2">

                  </textarea>
                </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
                <td colspan="2">3.</td>     
                <td>This memorandum has been prepared .....to support:</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                  <textarea rows="4" cols="150" v-model="guidance3">

                  </textarea>
                </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
                <td colspan="2">4.</td>     
                <td>This memorandum has been prepared .....to support:</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                  <textarea rows="4" cols="150" v-model="guidance4">

                  </textarea>
                </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
                <td colspan="2">5.</td>     
                <td>This memorandum has been prepared .....to support:</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                  <textarea rows="4" cols="150" v-model="guidance5">

                  </textarea>
                </td>
          </tr>          
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Supervisory Review:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  ______Approved&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;______Denied</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Signature:__________________________________<br />*For completion by Chief or Assistant Director</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Final Approval:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  ______Approved&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;______Denied</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Signature:__________________________________<br />*For completion by Chief or Assistant Director</td>
    </tr>    
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><button value="Save" @click.prevent="submitForm">Submit</button>&nbsp;<button type="button">Print</button></td>
  </tr>

  </table>
</div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/demo/webparts/pdf/travelMemo_2.js"></script>
```

```
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: {
    Title: '',
    from: '',
    Subj:'',
    To: '',
    guidance1:'',
    guidance2:'',
    guidance3:'',
    guidance4:'',
    guidance5:'',
    test: 'Hello World'     
  },
  methods: {
    submitForm: function() {
    alert("HELLO");
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Travel Request Memos');

        var itemCreateInfo =  new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
        oListItem.set_item('Title', 'Title field');
        oListItem.set_item('From', 'from field');
        oListItem.set_item('Subj', 'subject field');
        oListItem.set_item('To', 'to field');
        oListItem.set_item('Guidance1', this.guidance1);
        oListItem.set_item('Guidance2', this.guidance2);
        oListItem.set_item('Guidance3', this.guidance3);
        oListItem.set_item('Guidance4', this.guidance4);
        oListItem.set_item('Guidance5', this.guidance5);  

    clientContext.load(oListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(this.onAddSucceeded, this.onAddFailed);
  },
  onAddSucceeded: function(){
   alert("Item added");
  },
  onAddFailed: function(sender, args) {   
    alert(args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());  
  }                                         
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The internal name of the Title column is not always "Title". Which list template was used to create your list?

To find the internal name: Go to the list's properties page, in the Columns section, click your column's name. Check the end of the browser's URL to see the internal name.

For example, Created By is "Author".

```
...}&Field=Author
```

Comment: It says 'Title'          _layouts/15/FldEdit.aspx?List=%7BBD6BB27D-4B03-4DF9-BFEE-16079F8A9C27%7D&Field=Title

Comment: Here's the weird part. As I comment out each set_item() line 1 by 1, the same error shows referencing each column

Answer (score 0):

Your clientContext object does not have a URL.

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext( yourSiteUrl );
```

or if running in a SharePoint page:

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
```

Otherwise, your code looks nearly identical to here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185011(v=office.14)

I don't know anything about the Vue.js library, so I can't help you there.